# What use are SQL dates without date functions?

Tags: sql, datetime, semantics, abstraction

I've worked with various ORMs and database abstractions designed to make it easy to work with multiple databases, both relational and not. The more comprehensive solutions will usually give you access to some date functions that boil down to actual SQL (or whatever, in the case of non-SQL dbs). On the other hand, many of these abstractions don't provide direct access to SQL functions and you lose the ability to deal with dates directly. Instead, you're expected to use the upper-level language (PHP, Python, whatever) to do your date-wrangling, and finally only insert, select, what-have-you the formatted date.

So my question is this: if the SQL server never gets to do anything with the date itself, am I better off just using an int and putting epoch timestamps in it, or is there additional value to the database server "knowing" it's a date?

Comment: It could be useful when you access your database with tools which don't use your ORM wrapper. Using a 3rd party database management, report generation or data mining tool which accesses the database directly could be much more user-friendly when you have real dates in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using dates, store them as dates.

Not only does this make it easier to translate between the database and application, but when you need to do anything based on the dates (and you will, otherwise *why* have dates stored at all?).

That is, when you need to sort or query using the dates, you will not need to go trough special effort to re-convert to dates.

Comment: Not that I necessarily disagree with what you're saying, but the sort example doesn't make sense for me. If I use an epoch timestamp *int*, will it sort differently from a date?

Comment: @kojiro - No, but when you need to select a range, say everything in a specified month, you need to start calculating...

Comment: to be sure. But this question can be paraphrased, *if I'm going to need to do the calculations manually anyway…*

Comment: @kojiro - Problem with your suggestion is that you assume that you will never need to use dates as dates and that only your application will ever access this database.

Comment: A fair point. Accepted. I lean toward semantic correctness anyway.

Comment: @kojiro - Semantics are so important. Also the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) applies here, at least with regards to colleagues working with the system...

Answer (score 1):

Other than what `@Oded said`, if you **never ever use any date related functions**, Still there are some issues;

- At the moment, you `cannot store epoch timestamp in milliseconds into an INT` field (overflows).
- Timestamp without milliseconds will overflow *INT* on `Tue Jan 19 2038 @ 03:14:08 GMT+0000 (GMT)` as it will be greater than `2147483647`.
- *BUT*, Integer takes 4 bytes and Datetime takes 8 bytes. `You are better off 4 bytes if you are within above two limitations.`

Comment: There's always `BIGINT`, I suppose. That buys me time. :)

Comment: @kojiro , That was the only thing that I could think of :)